# How to perform load testing of webservice by importing CSV file

Tags: web-services, testing, load

How to perform load testing of a Web Service by importing CSV file(I want to perform load testing with real users exported from database )

Answer (score 0):

Try [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

In this link you will find a good example on how to use a CSV as source:
https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG